# Disabling click triggering on a checkbox inside a div with a click event in Ember

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have divs created with a #each loop. Each div have a click action and contains a checkbox. I want to prevent the checkbox from triggering the click event of its parent div. I am using Ember.js handlebars.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="conversations">   
    {{#each conv in model itemController='singleconv'}}
            <div class="conversation-content-wrapper" {{action "clickConv" conv preventDefault=false}}>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-closed" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-x"></i>Conversation closed</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-assignation" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-assign"></i>Conversation assigned</p></div>
                    <div class="history-message-assigned in-progress-reopen" style="display:none;"><p><i class="icon-re-opened"></i>Conversation re-opened</p></div>          
                <div class="conversation-history">          
                    <div class="conversation-time-history">{{{conv.timeAgoElement}}}</div>
                    <div class="conversation-details">
                        <span class="unread-numbers"></span>
                        {{input type='checkbox' checked=conv.isChecked bubbles="false"}}
                             <span class="conversation-name">{{conv.customer.name}}</span>
                             <span class="phone-number">{{conv.customer.cellPhoneNumber}}</span>
                            <p class="conversation-text">{{conv.lastMessage}}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                       
            </div>
    {{/each}}     
</script>
```

What is the most efficient way to do so? I did look onto the bubbles="false" attribute, but either I don't put it at the right place or it isn't made for this case.

Comment: Post you component js files for both components please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys here is how I did it.

I added a selectedConv property in my itemController. I set it to false everytime checkbox is clicked (doesn't matter its status). I then verify this property with a 'if property' in the triggered action click.

If true, code is executed. In the same action block, outside the if block, I then set the property to true, so when the div alone is clicked, the code will be executed. If its false (set when you click the checkbox), code wont be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just create an action for the checkbox but return false?

Actually having bubbles=false probably only works when you have an action defined on the element because after all, bubbles=false is supposed to go inside an action helper.

Comment: I tried putting an action on my checkbox returning false, but the click on the div still triggers.

Comment: Does the checkbox action definitely get called?

Comment: there is no checkbox action, it is an observer on a parameter who looks up the checked status